# How to extract the SOA DNS Server from a DNS Python Response

Tags: python, python-3.x, automation, scripting, dnspython

I'm trying to use DNS Python to lookup the SOA for a FQDN. From there, I am trying to isolate and extract the dns server name for the SOA, but I'm unable to find the correct object.

This is where I am at in my troubleshooting. I feel like i cam getting close with answer.response.additional, but it is still not the standalone server name.

Any advice on this? Thanks!

Code:

```
        import dns.resolver

        FQDN = 'testhostname.awesomedomain.com'

        answer = dns.resolver.query(FQDN, 'SOA', raise_on_no_answer=False)
        
        if answer.rrset is None:
            print(answer.response.authority[0].to_text())
            soa_data = answer.response.authority[0].to_text()
        else:
            print(answer)
            soa_data = answer
        
        rr = answer.response.authority[0]
        print(f"RR is {rr}")
        print(f"DataType is {rr.rdtype}")
        print(f"DNS SOA Type is {dns.rdatatype.SOA}")
        print(f"Target 1 is {rr.target}")
        print(f"Target 2 is {answer.canonical_name}")
        print(f"Target 3 is {answer.qname}")
        print(f"Target 4 is {answer.rdclass}")
        print(f"Target 5 is {answer.response}")
        print(f"Target 6 is {answer.response.additional}")
        print(f"Target 7 is {answer.response.additional.name}")
```

Comment: What do you mean by "lookup the SOA for a FQDN"? A SOA record is a required part of every DNS zone. Zones more or less correspond with *domain* names, not *host* names (FQDN is a hostname).

Comment: I want to scrape the DNS Server that is hosting the SOA record for a domain/zone from a FQDN.

Comment: What is the specific library that you're importing with `import dns.resolver`?

Answer (score -1):

Here is the method how would an admin get the information from the command line. Hope it helps, but you have to make the script yourself.

**Step 1**. Query your DNS server (or any *recursive* DNS server that you are allowed to use) for the A (IPv4, default) or AAAA (IPv6) record for the given hostname. In the following example I used the `www.ibm.com`.

CLI command: `dig www.ibm.com.`

The answer (with some lines deleted for brevity)

```
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;www.ibm.com.                   IN      A

;; ANSWER SECTION:
www.ibm.com.            3599    IN      CNAME   www.ibm.com.cs186.net.
www.ibm.com.cs186.net.  43199   IN      CNAME   outer-ccdn-dual.ibmcom.edgekey.net.
outer-ccdn-dual.ibmcom.edgekey.net. 21600 IN CNAME outer-ccdn-dual.ibmcom.edgekey.net.globalredir.akadns.net.
outer-ccdn-dual.ibmcom.edgekey.net.globalredir.akadns.net. 900 IN CNAME e2874.dscx.akamaiedge.net.
e2874.dscx.akamaiedge.net. 20   IN      A       92.123.17.145

;; AUTHORITY SECTION:
dscx.akamaiedge.net.    4000    IN      NS      n2dscx.akamaiedge.net.
dscx.akamaiedge.net.    4000    IN      NS      n6dscx.akamaiedge.net.

;; ADDITIONAL SECTION:
n2dscx.akamaiedge.net.  4000    IN      A       23.212.110.6
n6dscx.akamaiedge.net.  4000    IN      A       2.23.97.125
```

We see, the name is an alias (CNAME) of an alias etc. and it resolves to the `e2874.dscx.akamaiedge.net.` FQDN. We don't care about the IP address this time. We are interested in the AUTHORITY SECTION. There is the zone/domain where that FQDN belongs: `dscx.akamaiedge.net.`.

**Step 2**: Now ask for the SOA record for the domain from step 1.

CLI command: `dig -t soa dscx.akamaiedge.net.`

```
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;dscx.akamaiedge.net.           IN      SOA

;; ANSWER SECTION:
dscx.akamaiedge.net.    1000    IN      SOA     n0dscx.akamaiedge.net. hostmaster.akamai.com. 1611089512 1000 1000 1000 1800
```

And there is your SOA.

Note that the retrieved SOA happens to differ from the SOA for the `ibm.com.` domain, because the name is aliased. I hope I did correctly understand your comment about what SOA you are looking for.

Comment: Thanks. This is the procedure that I'm hoping to follow, but I'm hoping to get the result using Python3.